# Event code: 3005 Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred

Tags: asp.net

We have a Asp.net solution (having c# and vb.net code with Ajax). Was running fine in Test and when moved to Prod , it started giving JavaScript errors. And happens for many pages When checked server got the following error.

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 31/03/2014 13:48:10 
Event time (UTC): 31/03/2014 12:48:10 
Event ID: 37dd3345a5964cf19ac94b2c05976457 
Event sequence: 3 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/7862/Root-4-130407436897106054 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: D:\MSINetData\WWW\MT\ 
    Machine name: P01TSDES01

Process information: 
    Process ID: 28140 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: MethodAccessException 
    Exception message: Attempt to access method System.Management.Instrumentation.InstrumentedAttribute..ctor(System.String) in violation of security transparency rules failed.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.CheckLinktimeDemands(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeModule module, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit)
   at System.Web.UI.AssemblyCache.GetAjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute(Assembly assembly)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_DefaultAjaxFrameworkAssembly()
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager..ctor()
   at ASP.repository_projectcontact_aspx.__BuildControlToolkitScriptManager1()
   at ASP.repository_projectcontact_aspx.__BuildControlContent2(Control __ctrl)
   at System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container)
   at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.InstantiateInContentPlaceHolder(Control contentPlaceHolder, ITemplate template)
   at ASP.master_mt_master.__BuildControlMTMContent()
   at ASP.master_mt_master.__BuildControlform1()
   at ASP.master_mt_master.__BuildControlTree(master_mt_master __ctrl)
   at ASP.master_mt_master.FrameworkInitialize()
   at System.Web.UI.UserControl.InitializeAsUserControlInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



    Request information: 
    Request URL:
    Request path: /Repository/ProjectContact.aspx 
    User host address: 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: P01TSDES01\MX-PAR 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 5 
    Thread account name: P01TSDES01\MX-PAR 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.CheckLinktimeDemands(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeModule module, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit)
   at System.Web.UI.AssemblyCache.GetAjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute(Assembly assembly)
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_DefaultAjaxFrameworkAssembly()
   at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager..ctor()
   at ASP.repository_projectcontact_aspx.__BuildControlToolkitScriptManager1()
   at ASP.repository_projectcontact_aspx.__BuildControlContent2(Control __ctrl)
   at System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container)
   at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.InstantiateInContentPlaceHolder(Control contentPlaceHolder, ITemplate template)
   at ASP.master_mt_master.__BuildControlMTMContent()
   at ASP.master_mt_master.__BuildControlform1()
   at ASP.master_mt_master.__BuildControlTree(master_mt_master __ctrl)
   at ASP.master_mt_master.FrameworkInitialize()
   at System.Web.UI.UserControl.InitializeAsUserControlInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details: 

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're having security issue. asp:ScriptManager is a typical cause for this error. 
Maybe you should try adding this to your web.config:

```
<system.web>  
    <trust level="Full"/> 
</system.web>
```